# Flashbot Error in the simulation

Tags: flashbots

I am recovering a transaccion from Mempool and sending through flashbot.
The flashbot always respods m Simulation Error:

`err: nonce too high: address 0xE450CA3671395BBFE57273cFcA0c106A77D2224D, tx: 283 state: 0; txhash 0x8f6080e218cae71b321a122729fc01fe06e40b9d19968aaabc33f089f2fc087a.`

Address Neither hash are the data that appear in the original transacction.
Someone know something about this errro?

Comment: What nonce are you using in your tx payload ? You need to used last one + 1 (like you would for a normal tx)

Comment: The error is random, 90% of times the simulation returns me the error, but the other 10% the simulation pass